# Get all results for translated word using Google Translate API

Tags: google-translate

When translating from one language to another language, there may be multiple results. For example when we translate "book" from English to Spanish:

https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#auto/es/book

There are many results. However, when I try to use Google API, the response only includes one result:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "libro",
    "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

How I can get all of the translations?

Answer (score 1):

Google translation API doesn't allow to get multiple translations. Quote from their [faq](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq):

> Is it possible to get multiple translations of a word?
>
> No. This feature is only available via the web interface at
>   translate.google.com